# Twisted interval-bundles over a surface

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, fibre-bundles, surfaces

I am trying to understand interval bundles over orientable surfaces. I know of course the basic examples: trivial interval bundles are just products. From what I understand, there is only one non-trivial interval bundle over a given orientable surface, and it is a "twisted" interval bundle. Could someone give an idea of what a twisted interval bundle over an orientable surface looks like? A picture would especially be helpful (if its even possible to draw).

I am specifically interested in the case when the surface has boundary components, with or without genus. So if you only want to give that type of example, that's fine with me.

Comment: After passing to the 2-fold cover corresponding to the first Stiefel-Whitney class of the $I$-bundle you get the trivial bundle. Thus every nontrivial $I$-bundle can by visualized as the quotient  of $S\times I$ by an involution that acts freely on the surface $S$ factor and acts as multiplication by $-1$ on $I=[-1, 1]$. Perhaps, the case when $S=S^1\times I$ is the easiest to visualize.

Comment: @IgorBelegradek do you have a reference for this fact? I'd like to read more about it.

Comment: I don't know a reference; there cannot be one for every fact, but here is a sketch. There is a natural identification $H^1(S;\mathbb Z_2)$ with $Hom(H_1(S), \mathbb Z_2)=Hom(\pi_1(S), \mathbb Z_2)$, so a nontrivial $w_1$ of the $I$-bundle corresponds to a surjection $\pi_1(S)\to\mathbb Z_2$. Its kernel gives a 2-fold cover $\tilde S$ of $S$, and $w_1$ dies in this cover. Line (or $I$) bundles are classified by $w_1$ so the pullback of the $I$ bundle to $\tilde S$ is trivial.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not possible to "draw" a twisted $I$-bundle (over an orientable surface) in three-space without self-intersections of the horizontal boundary (and, I think, collisions of the fibers).  If you allow things to collapse a bit over an arc in the base, then there are drawings.  [image: interval bundles over annulus and Mobius strip]

In my figures, the grey surface is the *vertical boundary*, the white surface is the *horizontal boundary*, and the red arc is where I collapsed in order to make the drawing possible.

---

It is true that there is a unique (up to bundle isomorphism) orientation $I$-bundle over a non-orientable surface.  It is also true that there is a unique twisted $I$-bundle over a closed surface (*if* you allow automorphisms of the base).

But the uniqueness does not hold for surfaces with boundary.  For example, any connected double cover of a surface gives a twisted $I$-bundle.  But there are double covers of the four-holed two-sphere (say) which are not homeomorphic.  (To be concrete: there is one double cover which is a four-holed two-torus, and there is another double cover which is a six-holed two-sphere.) The resulting twisted $I$-bundles have non-homeomorphic horizontal boundaries, so are not "equivalent" as bundles (even when we allow automorphisms of the base).

Comment: This is helpful, thank you! This has sparked another question: is there a standard way to define a twisted I-bundle?

Comment: Umm, I suppose the definition of “twisted $I$-bundle” is “not a product $I$-bundle“. :)

Comment: Ha okay, not as helpful. How about this: I think I read somewhere that the orientation I-bundle over a surface (orientable or not) with at least one boundary component is always a 3d handlebody. Is it known what kind manifolds you can get when you take twisted I-bundles as in the question?

Comment: There are two kinds of handlebody - orientable and non-orientable.  The former is a boundary connect sum of copies of $S^1 \times D^2$ (the solid torus).  The latter is a boundary connect sum of copies of the unique non-orientable disk bundle over $S^1$ (the "solid Klein bottle"). Suppose that $F$ is a compact connected surface with boundary.  Suppose that $T$ is an $I$-bundle over $F$.  Then $T$ is a handlebody.  This handlebody is orientable if and only if $T$ is the orientation $I$-bundle.  (If $F$ is orientable, this means $T$ is a product.)

Comment: Okay thank you, this is very helpful. Does this then mean that if there is an I-bundle $J$ (over a surface $S$ with boundary, orientable or not) embedded in an orientable handlebody $H$ such that the interior boundary of $J$ is a subset of $\partial H$, then $J$ must be the orientation I-bundle over $S$?

Comment: If $J$ embeds in an orientable three-manifold, then $J$ is isomorphic (as an $I$-bundle) to the orientation $I$--bundle over $S$.  (That is: there is no need to control the homeomorphism type of the ambient space.  Also, there is no need to place conditions on where the boundary goes.)

Comment: Another clarifying question: when you say "it is true that there is a unique (up to bundle isomorphism) orientation I-bundle over a non-orientable surface", are you including surfaces with boundary in this statement?

Comment: There is a unique (up to bundle isomorphism) orientation I-bundle over any surface (in fact, any manifold), regardless of whether or not it has boundary.

Comment: Is there a neat way to show that the total spaces of twisted $I$-bundles over a non-orientable surface are all diffeomorphic? A possible proof would consists in showing that the mapping class group of the base acts transitively on the set of non-trivial Stiefel-Whitney classes. However the MCG of $\mathbb {R P}^2\# \cdots \#\mathbb {R P}^2$ does not seem to be elementary to understand.

Comment: @Overflowian - there is no neat way, because it is not true. “Twisted” means “not a product bundle”.  The isomorphism classes of I-bundles are parameterised by homomorphisms from the fundamental group to $\mathbb{Z} / 2 \mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: @SamNead $H^1(X;\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})$ parametrizes isomorphism classes of $I$-bundles but their total spaces may be diffeomorphic.

Comment: Ah.  Good point.  But it is still not true.  For example, the orientability of the total space of the bundle is a diffeomorphism invariant.  There should be further topological invariants to distinguish these spaces.  For example, suppose that the base surface has no boundary. Look at the size of a maximal collection of properly embedded disjoint Mobius bands.  It seems to me that this number ranges from zero up to linear in the genus.

Comment: @SamNead If my understanding is correct, Proposition 1.1.12 of Martelli's "Geometric Topology" asserts that there is only one total space of I-bundle which is orientable. Since the total space is orientable on a not-orientable base precisely when the I-bundle is not-orientable we get that the total space are all the same for $w_1(\xi)\neq 0$ Stiefel-Whitney class.

More concretly, consider the Klein bottle $K$, since $Aut(K)$ acts transitively on $H^1(K; Z/2)\setminus \{0\}$, by pulling back a fixed non-orientable $I$-bundle  via $Aut(K)$ we can get every non-trivial $w_1$.

Comment: "the total space is orientable on a not-orientable base precisely when the I-bundle is not-orientable" I believe that this is incorrect.  If the I-bundle is not orientable, the total space may or may not be orientable.  As for your Klein bottle example - consider the possibility of reversing the fiber orientation on both loops $a$ and $b$ where $\pi_1(K) = \langle a, b \mid abA = B \rangle$.

Comment: @SamNead thank you for taking the time of discussing this. I think I undestand now where my mistake was, I have written an answer here about this orientabiility matter: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4425410/fiber-bundle-orientability-vs-manifold-orientability/4776574#4776574
It seems that the unique orientable total space is actually also distinguished by the isomorphism class of the bundle, since there is only one Stiefel-Whitney class that does the job.

Answer (score 6):

An $I$-bundle over $M$ amounts bijectively to a $2$-fold cover (the boundary of the total space!) so they are classified by the cohomology group $H^1(M;\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})$.

Think to the Mobius strip, a twisted I-bundle over the circle. The most simple case of twisted I-bundle over a surface is over the annulus $M = [0,1]\times S^1$; it consists of a Mobius strip over each circle $t\times S^1$, $t\in[0,1]$ (Sam's nice drawing 1). In any case, if $M$ is orientable, the total space of any twisted I-bundle is a nonorientable $3$-manifold, hence you cannot embed it (nor even immerse it) into $\mathbb{R}^3$, if this is what you mean by "a picture". On the other hand, you will easily find a twisted bundle over the Mobius strip whose total space is embedded in $\mathbb{R}^3$  (Sam's nice drawing 2).

To get nonisomorphic twisted bundles: over the $2$-torus, there are $3$ nonisomorphic twisted $I$-bundles; and the same holds over the pair of pants (a big disk $D_1$ minus two small disks $D_2$, $D_3$, whose boundary has three circle components: for $i=1$, $2$, $3$, the $i$-th bundle is not twisted over $\partial D_i$ but twisted over the two other components). But these ones are isomorphic up to diffeomorphisms of $M$. To get an example of two twisted I-bundles not isomorphic even modulo diffeomorphisms, take for $M$ a big disk minus $3$ small disks.  The one twisted bundle is twisted over exactly $2$ boundary components, the other over the $4$ boundary components.

Comment: Anybody who says my drawings are "nice" gets an automatic upvote.  :)